# Filtering grep results using a negative grep against an Array

Tags: bash, grep

I am using grep to look for a list of words in the following fashion:

```
grep -HniIr --color=always "for" "$SEARCH_DIR"
```

And I would like to ignore lines that contain any of the elements of an array named $superStringIgnoreArray. An example of $superStringIgnoreArray is below:

> before California form format forms forth information Information
>   perform performance sourceforge therefore Therefore unenforceable

I've tried using the -v -f flags (shown below) against the array, to reduce results but it is not working (I still get lines which only contain a word/element/string from $superStringIgnoreArray).

```
 grep -HniIr --color=always "for" "$SEARCH_DIR"* | grep -vi -f <(printf '%s\n' "${superStringIgnoreArray[@]}") | tee "$OUTPUT_FILE"
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your command should work. Are you sure it doesn't?

Comment: I am. Using the instance above I get hits for every one of those words in $superStringIgnoreArray

Comment: If you send the output of the first occurence of **grep** into another program, the option *--color* makes no sense. The generated escape sequences for switching colors can even interfere with the pattern matching of the second occurence of **grep**.

Comment: Pierra Francois ... Yahtzee, that was the problem, you are awesome.